# How to access variables which are inside try-catch?

Tags: java, android, json

Im doing something like

```
JSONArray json = uf.getAllRows();
(int x = 0; x <= json.length(); x++) {
JSONObject jo = json.getJSONObject(x); //Eclipse is suggesting that use try-catch here.

String name = jo.getString("username");
mainll[x] = new LinearLayout(this);
mainll[x].setId(x);
mainll[x].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mainll[x].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
.
.
.
.
}
```

if i use try catch than "jo" is not recognized at the following line:

```
String name = jo.getString("username");
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: set 'breakpoint' and 'debug' , plz, You will figure out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap everything

```
try{
  JSONArray json = uf.getAllRows();
  (int x = 0; x <= json.length(); x++) {
  JSONObject jo = json.getJSONObject(x); //Eclipse is suggesting that use try-catch here.

  String name = jo.getString("username");
  mainll[x] = new LinearLayout(this);
  mainll[x].setId(x);
  mainll[x].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  mainll[x].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
JSONObject jo;
try {
    jo = json.getJSONObject(x);
} catch (...) {
    jo = null; // or other error handling
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a Simple Solution would be, You can declare your variable outside the try..catch block so you will be able to access it.

for example,

```
String myVariable = "";

try
{
     .
     .
     .
     myVariable = "Some Assignment"; 
}
catch ( Exception e ) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your **jo** variable outside `try/catch` as:

```
String name;
try{

String name = jo.getString("username");
mainll[x] = new LinearLayout(this);
mainll[x].setId(x);
mainll[x].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mainll[x].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 ///
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray json = uf.getAllRows();
JSONObject jo = null;
String name = "";

(int x = 0; x <= json.length(); x++) {
   try{
     jo = json.getJSONObject(x); //Eclipse is suggesting that use try-catch here.
   }catch(Exception ex){}

   name = jo.getString("username");
   mainll[x] = new LinearLayout(this);
   mainll[x].setId(x);
   mainll[x].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   mainll[x].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```